# Disabling breakpoints of the Bootstrap 4 grid

Tags: bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm rolling out the front-end of a web app that is using Bootstrap 4 alpha 6 as the framework.

The data-heavy app is designed to work on screens from ~960px wide or larger, so I want to limit the Bootstrap grid's useage to `-lg-` and `-xl-` grid breakpoints with `-lg-` being the smallest/default.

Removing the lower breakpoints from the map like so does prevent the grid classes for `-xs-`, `-sm-` and `-md-` from being generated but it also does likewise for `-lg-` causing everything to snap to a single 100% width column.

```
$grid-breakpoints: (

  lg: 0px, // originally 992px
  xl: 1200px
) !default;
@include _assert-ascending($grid-breakpoints, "$grid-breakpoints");
@include _assert-starts-at-zero($grid-breakpoints);
```

I also don't see a way to edit the media queries that would be necessary to achieve what I'm looking for.

Anyone tried this or have any ideas of how it could be done? My other theory is to set:

`$enable-grid-classes:       false !default;`

... and make a custom layout using the [mixins provided](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#sass-mixins)?

Answer (score 0):

I think `$grid-breakpoints: (lg: 0px, xl: 1200px) !default;` does the job.
Bootstrap 4 dropped the `xs` infix from the lowest breakpoint.

After this change on sass variables the lowest/default breakpoint is `lg`. **Forget** `-lg-`. Your grid classes are now `col-**` for every viewport up to `1199px` and `col-xl-**` for every viewport larger than `1200px`.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 col-xl-3 text-center" style="background-color: red;">
        50% - 25%
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-xl-9 text-center" style="background-color: green;">
        50% - 75%
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing up some confusion I had around the new `col-x` classes and how that operates. That all works but the only issue is that the `.container` width (which is set to 960px) is for some reason being ignored and the layout just continues to shrink.